# Stop Applescript from opening empty terminal window

Tags: applescript

I have an Applescript that opens a terminal window within my virtual environment and another window within my virtual environment with an instance of jupyter notebook.

```
tell application "Terminal"

do script "cd /Users/myusername/myfolder && source myfolder_venv/bin/activate"
do script "cd /Users/myusername/myfolder && source myfolder_venv/bin/activate &&jupyter notebook"
activate
end tell
end run
```

Instead of 2 terminal windows, it opens 3, but only when the terminal app is not running. Otherwise it opens 2 windows. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the opened window as location

```
tell application "Terminal"

    do script "cd /Users/myusername/myfolder && source myfolder_venv/bin/activate" in window 1
    do script "cd /Users/myusername/myfolder && source myfolder_venv/bin/activate &&jupyter notebook" in window 1
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: Does not work. Can’t get window 1 of application "Terminal". Terminal got an error: Can’t get window 1. (-1728)

Comment: The error occurs if Terminal.app runs and no window is open. If Terminal.app is not running the script is supposed to work. You can insert `reopen` after the `tell` line to create a new window if there is none.